Is the reciprocal golden ratio well approximated by this exponentially sparse series of reciprocal Fibonacci numbers?
Let $1/\phi= \phi-1\approx0.618\,$ denote the reciprocal golden ratio and $\mathrm F(k)\;(k=0,1,...)$ the Fibonacci numbers, where $\mathrm F(0)=0,\mathrm F(1)=1,$ and $\mathrm F(k+1)=\mathrm F(k)+\mathrm F(k-1)\;(k=1,2,...)$. With the help of two online resources 1, 2, I noticed that
$$\frac1\phi=\frac1{\mathrm F(3)}+\frac1{\mathrm F(6)}-\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{\mathrm F(3\cdot2^k)}-\epsilon,$$
where $n=7$ and $\epsilon\approx7.03\times10^{-161}.$ The online list of Fibonacci numbers did not go as far as $\mathrm F(768)$. With each extension of the series so far, the error reduced (roughly quadratically) in magnitude to approximately the next term. The following questions arise.
$(1)\;$ Does increasing $n$ from $7$ to $8$ improve the approximation significantly?
$(2)\;$ More ambitiously, do we get equality when $n\to\infty\,$?

WA can handle many more terms for the sum.

@lulu : When I calculate $$\frac1\phi-\frac1{\mathrm F(3)}-\frac1{\mathrm F(6)}+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{\mathrm F(3\cdot2^k)},$$ on Wolfram Alpha, it returns $5.55112 \times10^{-17}$. The online Maths is Fun Full Precision Calculator that I used calculates (by the default setting) to 200 decimal places which, along with Planet Math's full precision for $\mathrm F(384)$, is sufficient for $n=7$.  I don't know what precision is claimed by WA, but anyway it looks wrong to me.

Not sure what you mean.  When I use $n=100$ I get an error of about $10^{-107}$ which is close enough to $0$ for me.    The sum is close to a geometric series, maybe one can manipulate it usefully.  Didn't try.

The relevant OEIS page appears to confirm the sum (again, didn't go through all the details).   Key point is to establish the recursion $\sum \frac 1{a_n}=\frac 54-\frac {a_{n-1}}{a_n}$ where $a_n=\frac 1{F_{3\times 2^n}}$.  Of course, the ratio gives rise to the golden mean for large $n$.

Sorry, what I wrote was unclear.  The sum should have read $\sum_{i=0}^n\frac 1{a_i}$.

@lulu : Sorry from me too: that $n$ in the upper sum limit in my comment was meant to be $7$, as in the question, which was what I used to calculate the error of $7.03\times10^{-161}$.

@lulu : I have found a high-precision mode on WA. However, when I ask it for PRECISION Fibonacci[384], it returns $\infty$. So WA isn't up to the job.

As I say, the trick is to establish that regression.  The OEIS page simply asserts it but perhaps it isn't hard to establish.  Hard part appears to be spotting it, really.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I don't think there's anything to chat about.  I doubt that recursion is difficult to prove (spotting it seems like it would be a challenge, but that's been done).  Anyway, I suggest trying to prove it.

The (corrected) regression/recursion in your second comment, namely $$\sum_{i=0}^n\frac 1{a_i}=\frac 54-\frac {a_{n-1}}{a_n},$$ where $a_n=\frac 1{F_{3\times 2^n}},$ needs some editing. As it stands, it is already wrong for $n=1$ , when $a_0=\frac12$, $a_1=\frac18$, and $1/a_0+1/a_1=10$, while $\frac54-a_0/a_1=-\frac{11}4$.

I'm just quoting the recursion presented by OEIS.  Their notation is a bit sloppy, for instance, I guessed at the meaning of their F(3*2^n-1)  Perhaps they didn't mean the $-1$ to be in the exponent.  My experience with that site, however, is that everything has been checked pretty carefully, even if the formatting sometimes leads to confusion.  But, again, I haven't checked it so have no idea whether it is fundamentally sound or not.

@lulu : Yes, that explains it: the $-1$ should not be in the exponent. The paper by Hoggatt & Bicknell cited by OEIS has the proof and (affirmatively) answers my question. Thank you. I intend to delete this question in due course, since nobody likes it, and it has only earned me downvotes.

There's nothing wrong with the question.  I'll upvote it to (partially) compensate.  If the proof of the recursion is short enough, you might want to post it below.  It's far from obvious (as far as I know, there is no useful description of the total sum $\sum 1{F_n}$ for example.

Using Mathematica $\epsilon_6=1.25\times 10^{-80}$,  $\epsilon_7=7.03\times 10^{-161}$,   $\epsilon_8=2.21\times 10^{-321}$,  $\epsilon_9=2.19\times 10^{-642}$

Using @M.E.W.'s answer $\epsilon_n \sim \sqrt{5}   \left(2-\sqrt{5}\right)^{2^{n+1}}$ reproduces the above numbers.

I prove statement $(2)$ to be true and you can use my results to easily verify $(1)$.
By the Binet-formula we have $$F(m)=\frac{\phi^m- \psi^m}{\sqrt5}$$ where   $\psi = \frac{-\sqrt5 +1}{2} $ and $\phi =\frac{\sqrt5 +1}{2}= \frac{-1}{\psi}$. Now set $\psi ^3 = x$ and notice that then we have $$F(3m) = \frac{(\frac{-1}{\psi})^{3m}- \psi^{3m}}{\sqrt5} = \frac{(-x)^{-m} - x^m}{\sqrt5}~.$$
With this we can transform the sum of interest in to a telescoping sum: $$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{F(3\cdot 2^k)} = \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{\sqrt5}{x^{-2^k}-x^{2^k}}=\sqrt5 \sum_{k=2}^n \frac{x^{2^k}}{1-x^{2^{k+1}}}=\sqrt5 \sum_{k=2}^n \left( \frac{x^{2^k}}{1-x^{2^{k}}} -\frac{x^{2^{k+1}}}{1-x^{2^{k+1}}} \right)~.$$
By canceling the terms on the right we get $$\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{F(3\cdot 2^k)} = \sqrt5 \left( \frac{x^{4}}{1-x^{4}} - \underbrace{\frac{x^{2^{n+1}}}{1-x^{2^{n+1}}}}_{\to 0 }\right )$$
where the second fraction vanishes for ${n \to \infty}$, because $ |x| < 1$. Hence, we conclude $$\frac{1}{F(3)} + \frac{1}{F(6)} - \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{F(3 \cdot 2^k)} = \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{8} -\sqrt5 \frac{\psi^{12}}{1-\psi^{12}} = \frac{1}{\phi} ~.$$ The last equality is obtained by some algebra with the definition of $\psi$ and $\phi$, which I omit.
